# Problem Deserializing JSON to objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have the below response from the API in a console application written in C#:

```js
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "123",
          "uri": "456",
          "type": "789"
        },
        "PERNR": "1",
        "USRID": "2"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "159",
          "uri": "951",
          "type": "753"
        },
        "PERNR": "4",
        "USRID": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And used the below code to deserialize:

```js
    public class d
    {
        public results results { get; set; }
    }

    public class results
    {
        public string PERNR { get; set; }
        public string USRID { get; set; }
        public __metadata __metadata { get; set; }
    }

    public class __metadata
    {
        public string id { get; set;}
        public string uri { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

```
        var serilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        d output = serilizer.Deserialize<d>(response.Content);
```

But the result is null. Is there any problem in the definition of the classes?

Comment: That JSON string isn't a `d` object, it contains an attribute named `d` that matches the `d` type. `d` in turn contains an array, not a single item

Comment: Why is `JavaScriptSerializer` used? That's an obsolete class with several restrictions. It doesn't even support proper date serialization. That was a legacy class that was replaced by JSON.NET in ASP.NET Web API and System.Text.Json in ASP.NET Core 3

Answer (score 1):

The issue is results is an array in your json, where in your class, it is an object. Change it to

```
 public class d
 {
     public Result[] results { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The properties should start with a capital letter, to match the case of the properties in the JSON response. Change the class definitions as follows:

```
public class D
{
public Results[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
public string PERNR { get; set; }
public string USRID { get; set; }
public Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
public string id { get; set;}
public string uri { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Change deserialize line to:

```
var serilizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
D output = serilizer.Deserialize<D>(response.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JSON to C# converter like [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/) or Visual Studio's [Paste JSON As Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) you'll get :

```
public class Root
{
    public D d { get; set; }
}

public class D
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Metadata __metadata { get; set; }
    public string PERNR { get; set; }
    public string USRID { get; set; }
}
```

There are two important differences :

1. The JSON document contains a root element with an attribute named `d`, not a `D` object
2. `D.results` is a collection of `Result` objects, not a single object